# Java WebDriver нажатие на input

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

всем привет, как мне имитировать нажатие на эту кнопку ?

```
<div style="margin: 5px; display: inline-block; position: relative; bottom: 8px;">
<input class="val_m" style="width: 37px; height: 27px; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; color: #87a96b;" type="text" maxlength="2" name="capcha_mat_surf_02e74f10e0327ad868d138f2b4fdd6f0" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.findElement(By.className("val_m")).click();
```

Comment: Этот способ не работает

Comment: @as1andrey1 а собственно где сама кнопка? в коде вижу input type="text"